# Why are real numbers on the number line but complex numbers aren't?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers, division-ring

This seems like a question that should be relatively easy to answer, but for the life of me I simply can't figure it out. My question is relatively simply put in the title, and the answer seems like it should be that $\mathbb{R}$ is a one dimensional space over itself whereas $\mathbb{C}$ is a two dimensional space over it. But this is unsatisfactory. Both of these fields are infinitely dimensional vector spaces over the rationals, but only $\mathbb{R}$ coexists in the same "number line". By that logic, $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ ought to be a plane, but since that's just a subfield of the reals, its on the number line as well. I suspect the answer to this has to do with the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is totally ordered, but shouldn't it be possible to define a totally ordering on $\mathbb{C}$ that also respects the preexisting ordering? But then why is $\mathbb{H}$ 4-dimensional? Neither it nor $\mathbb{C}$ have apparent orderings, so what property of the former prevent is from residing within the complex plane?

Comment: While we can indeed put an ordering on $\mathbb{C}$, we cannot do so **in a way compatible with the field structure** - see the notion of [ordered (or order*able*) fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field).

Comment: Just to clarify, $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a $2$ dimensional space, but $\mathbb{C}$ is a $1$ dimensional space.

Comment: @copper.hat $\mathbb{C}$ is a 2 dimensional space over $\mathbb{R}$. It's only one dimensional over itself. It satisfies all of the vector space axioms for real spaces and has a basis set of $\{1,i\}$

Comment: The concept of dimension depends on the base field. Sure, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ is contained in the "real line", but the reals look like a line because you are seing it from the point of view of the reals.

However $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ has dimension $2$ over $\mathbb Q$, so if you see it from $\mathbb Q$ you will see it as if it were a plane. For example, the same way you can reflect the complex plane around $\mathbb R$ with complex conjugation which sends $i\to -i$, you can reflect $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ around $\mathbb Q$ using the conjugation that sends $\sqrt 2 \mapsto -\sqrt 2$.

Comment: I think @NoahSchweber has captured the essential thing here - the line provides a model for numbers in order. You can tell when a number is greater than zero, or between two others, by where the numbers fit on the line. We can fit integers or rational numbers or real numbers in a line according to an order which is compatible with the arithmetic involved. The key concept is order rather than dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer:*

I think the right way to make your question precise is to ask about the relationship between the *algebraic* and *geometric* natures of the real numbers. The key point in this context is not that there is an ordering of $\mathbb{R}$, but rather that there is an ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ **which plays well with the algebraic structure**. Formally, the ordering $\le$ satisfies the following algebraic properties:

- $\le$ is a total ordering: that is, it is antisymmetric, transitive, and reflexive.
- $a\le b$ implies $a+c\le b+c$ for all $c$.
- $a\le b$ implies $ac\le bc$ for all $0\le c$.

These properties, together with some basic algebraic properties of addition and multiplication, constitute the [ordered field axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field) - so the point here is that $\mathbb{R}$ equipped with the usual ordering is an ordered field. Moreover, this ordering is **unique** in the sense that no other ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ turns it into an ordered field, and is **algebraically definable** since $a\le b$ iff there is some $x$ with $a+x^2=b$. All of this together says that we have a really nice way of ordering the real numbers.

By contrast, nothing of the sort will work for $\mathbb{C}$. Although we can put an ordering on $\mathbb{C}$, there is no way to do so which will satisfy the algebraic properties above. This is a good exercise *(HINT: break into cases depending on whether $i$ is taken to be $\le0$ or $\ge0$)*.

Comment: So in general can we consider the dimension of a ring is it's dimension as a vector space over the largest ordered subring?